# Accessing data in Google Drive tables with Google App maker

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I access the data contained in Google drive tables?

I created some basic apps after reading the tutorials, but I'm unable to to see the sample data I entered.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). If you created some basic apps after reading the tutorials, pick the one that is closest to what you want and show the code to provide context for your question.

Comment: It is okish question for App Maker. The short answer is that there's no first party viewer for Drive Tables. I'll share some tricks on Tuesday.

Comment: @Jason Aller...there is no code....but it is a technical doubt

Comment: Pavel Shkleinik ...waiting for your tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** Don't use Drive Tables

App Maker gives you power to connect to [Cloud SQL instance](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql), that you can access through [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#connect_to_your_instance_using_the_db_client_client_in_the_cloud_shell) or connect with some tools like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

**Pros**

- Works nice if you have your own Cloud SQL instance

**Cons**

- This approach falls short in environments with shared Cloud SQL instances
- Cloud SQL is not free

**Option 2:** Export data to spreadsheet

Regardless what data backend you are using you can [dump all your data to spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#how_you_can_export_data).

**Cons**

- Basically it is one-way data access (read only), unless you want to mess with importing edited data back to your deployemnt...

**Option 3:** Drag'n'drop way

There is an option to keep *Debug* page and drop on it tables/forms for models you want to look it.

**Pros**

- Seamless access to data directly from you development environment (browser).

**Cons**

- It is hard to maintain such *Debug* especially when you are actively working on your database structure.
- Need to think about security and hide the page from your end users.
- Need to keep dedicated datasource(s) for the debug tables/forms, that should have no filters applied (at this time there is no client-side analogue of `app.models.MyModel.newQuery()` server-side API).

**Option 4:** Drag'n'drop way (advanced edition!)

The basic idea is to create a page with dynamic table (to view/edit data) and form (to add records). Using this highly dynamic page will eliminate shortage #1 from the option #3:
[image: Editor -> Model]
[image: Editor -> Layout]
[image: Runtime -> Table]
[image: Runtime -> Form]

This approach has similar pros and cons as previous one plus there are some App Maker limitations that make it hard to implement (but it is doable on some extent).